# Easy way to send a message to a bundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a SIMBL bundle and I'm wondering if there is an existing library that would make it easy for me to send some sort of command (perhaps over a socket) to my library without me building a tcp server from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use NSDistributedNotificationCenter, most likely.